# Can anyone show or give the download link for AEM / CQ5

Tags: aem

i want learn the aem /cq5 so Can anyone show or give the download link for AEM / CQ5 please

Answer (score 1):

AEM is a comercial product, you can have it either by working on a project that already bought Production licenses. or your employer is part of the Adobe partner program  - SPP. Other way it will be either impossible or illegal :(

Answer (score 0):

Though you would need a license to procure the Adobe product, there are options to learn & understand the basics:

1. just create an Adobe ID and download old CQ basics from here
   -https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/aem-previous-versions.html

if you have understood the very basics of AEM, then the runnable JAR from Apache sling - https://sling.apache.org/downloads.cgi would be very handy.

You can play around with this JAR (which comes with a built-in JCR repository where you can use the JCR API - the core of AEM)

please go ver the below before jump in to the JAR:
https://sling.apache.org/documentation.html
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/2_Introduction.html
http://felix.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-examples-and-presentations/apache-felix-osgi-tutorial.html